# Do you need to add an L at the end of initializing a long?

Tags: java, long-integer

If i want to initialize a long of `1` or `0` do i need to add `L` to the end?

```
long l = 0L;
long k = 1L;
```

versus

```
long l = 0;
long k = 1;
```

Does it matter for low values?

Answer (score 6):

> If i want to initialize a long of 1 or 0 do i need to add `L` to the end?

Only if the value is larger than will fit in an `int`. Without the `L` (or `l`, but don't use that), [the number is an `int`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1).

> Does it matter for low values?

Not at all. Java's `int`-to-`long` conversion is [well-defined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2), and works across the `int` range.

That doesn't mean that doing so is wrong in any way, of course. You might be doing it for clarity's sake, for instance.